# How do you successfully integrate the logical and and the logical or (&& ||) expressions for a series of values?

Tags: javascript, html

I was assigned a homework assignment- which I have otherwise somewhat successfully completed- where we were tasked with constructing a page to roll a series of dice. The first button was to generate the event of rolling 5 dice simultaneously and has worked thusly, so I know that there isn't a larger issue with the page in itself. The second button is to imitate the roll of two dice for the game of craps. (The assignment is as follows: In this problem, you will roll 2 die.
·        If the die show a 1 and a 1, output “Snake Eyes!”
·        If the sum of the die is a 7, output “Lucky 7s!”
·        If the first die shows a 6 and the second die shows a 6, output “High Sixes!”
·        For all others, simply output the results of the two die.) 
When the dice roll High Sixes or the else expression, it outputs the expression successfully in the empty div section. I am having the difficulty with the logical && and the logical or || expressions necessary for the concept of "lucky 7's", which is an event where the two dice roll and add up to 7. For some reason, the snake eyes expression is no longer working either, even though it had previously successfully outputted. I have used different javascript code checkers and tried a bunch of different configurations a bunch of different times, and can't quite figure out how to output.

I have tried simply stating in the if statement that if ((cfirstDie + csecondDie) == 7) then to use the inner html to output "lucky 7's", but have since tried making that into a variable. I have also tried writing out every single option (if cfirstDie == 6 && csecondDie == 1 || cfirstDie == 1 && csecondDie == 1 || cfirstDie == 3 && csecondDie == 4) ect ect and that didn't work. I'm completely lost as to what is going on after all the different configurations and feel like I'm missing something. I also don't understand why the Snake eyes expression previously worked and hasn't since I made some alterations to the lucky 7's expression.

```
 <div id="problem_two">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function rollCraps()
{
var cfirstDie = (Math.random()*6) +1;
cfirstDie = parseInt(cfirstDie);
var csecondDie = (Math.random()*6) +1;
csecondDie = parseInt(csecondDie);

var snakeEyes = "<h1>Snake Eyes!</h1>";
var luckySevens = "<h1>Lucky 7s!</h1>";
var highSixes = "<h1>High Sixes!</h1>";
var sumDie = (cfirstDie + csecondDie);
var anythingElse = ("1)" + cfirstDie + " " + "2)" + csecondDie);

if (cfirstDie == 1 && csecondDie == 1)
    document.getElementById("output_results").innerHTML = 
  snakeEyes;

else if (sumDie == 7)
    document.getELementById("output_results").innerHTML = 
luckySevens;

else if (cfirstDie == 6 && csecondDie == 6)
    document.getElementById("output_results").innerHTML = 
 highSixes;

else
    document.getElementById("output_results").innerHTML = 
anythingElse;


   }
</script>

  <input type="button" id="btnCraps" 
  style="background- 
  color:#ffffff;color:#0000FF;width:150px;height:40px;" value="Roll 
  the Die!"
  onclick="rollCraps()">
 </div>
```

The output displays if the die rolls high sixes or any of the else rolls. Otherwise nothing displays in the empty div section.

http://studentweb.cdm.depaul.edu/~bnelso41/die_roll.html
Sorry for the absolutely horrendous CSS- my teacher asked for it.

Comment: you need to do `if ... else if .... else if ...` etc - i.e. simply put `else` before the two middle `if`

Comment: Thank you! That helped the snake eyes expression to appear, but the high 7's still does not unfortunately

Comment: You have a syntax error preventing "Lucky 7s" from being displayed (and you did not include your `#output_results` element in the html posted with your question but I am assuming it is actually there on your end). `document.getELementById` should not have a capital "L" but instead should be `document.getElementById`. In the future you can find these sorts of things pretty easily by checking the browser console for errors.